# how to change annotation colors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How can I change the color of annotation frame? I've looked in appearance settings and in editor settings but I can't find ir anywhere..

Current one is too dark for me.

I am using Windows

[image]

Comment: Color inside the frame. The one that is getting darker...

Comment: It uses the system colors..

Comment: Do you mean background color of quick fix? Can you draw a red arrow pointing to element color you want to change?

Comment: Yes, the background of the quick fix.